# How to select the nearby key in python dictionary?

Tags: python

Please consider the below Python code:

```
def allot():
    dict2 = {'1': 1, '2': 1, '3': 0, '4': , '5': 1}
    allotted_id = None

    for k in dict2:
        usr_id = 3
        if (str(usr_id) != k):
            continue;

        if ((str(usr_id) == k) and (dict2[str(usr_id)] == 1)):

            print("\n user Requested Id : ", usr_id)
            print("\n user Requested Id is available ! ")
            allotted_id = k
            break;
        else:
            print("\n user Requested Id : ", usr_id)
            print("\n user Requested Id is not available ! ")
            usr_id = usr_id + 1
            if (dict2[str(usr_id)] == 1):
                allotted_id = usr_id
                break;

    print('So allotted dict2 Id', allotted_id)

allot()
```

In the **"dict2"**, `if values == 1 then it is active or if values == 0` then it is inactive. Here, match the `usr_id` with key id in `dict2`.

**Case 1:** `dict2 = {'1': 1, '2': 1, '3': 1, '4': 1, '5': 1}`. Now usr_id==3 and dict2 key '3'==1. so allotted `id=3`.

**Case 2:** `dict2 = {'1': 1, '2': 1, '3': 0, '4': 1, '5': 1}`. Now `usr_id==3` and dict2 key '3'==0 . Then next active id is allotted.So allotted id=4.

**Case 3:** `dict2 = {'1': 1, '2': 1, '3': 0, '4': 0, '5': 1}`. Now `usr_id==3` and dict2 key '3' & '4'==0 . So the next nearest active id to the `usr_id` want allocate (is nothing but key id '2').How to do it?

Guide me for my **case 3** scenario. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `'4': ,` is not valid python. Please edit your code to that it's actually valid python.

Comment: Why are you iterating the keys in the dict, rather than just doing `v = dict2[str(usr_id)]` or `v = dict2.get(str(usr_id))`?

Comment: Why are you storing the 'usr ids' as strings in the dictionary if they're actually numbers?

Comment: @Tom Dalton: I want to select the next nearest active key based on usr_id value position either left or right side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want no efficiency changes to the code, you're overwriting the usr_id in the `for k in dict2` loop.

```
def allot():
    dict2 = {'1': 1, '2': 1, '3': 0, '4': , '5': 1}
    allotted_id = None

    usr_id = 3  # Move this out of the loop

    for k in dict2:       
        if (str(usr_id) != k):
            continue;

        if ((str(usr_id) == k) and (dict2[str(usr_id)] == 1)):

            print("\n user Requested Id : ", usr_id)
            print("\n user Requested Id is available ! ")
            allotted_id = k
            break;
        else:
            print("\n user Requested Id : ", usr_id)
            print("\n user Requested Id is not available ! ")
            usr_id = usr_id + 1
            if (dict2[str(usr_id)] == 1):
                allotted_id = usr_id
                break;

    print('So allotted dict2 Id', allotted_id)

allot()
```

You can write this code to do more checks and utilise the dictionary structure a bit more...

```
def allot():
    # Variables to Enter
    dict2 = {1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 1}
    usr_id = 3

    # Boolean Variables
    allotted_id = None
    upper_exhausted = False
    lower_exhausted = False

    # Need to calculate the min and max to know when to stop searching
    max_id = max(dict2.keys())
    min_id = min(dict2.keys())

    # Check the initial ID
    if dict2[usr_id] == 0:
        print("ID {} inactive. Continuing search.".format(usr_id))
    else:
        allotted_id = usr_id

    # Run two searches - one increasing through the dictionary 
    # and one decreasing through the dictionary
    upper_usr_id = usr_id + 1
    lower_usr_id = usr_id - 1

    # Run loop whilst the max and min dict key haven't been reached 
    # AND there's no allotted ID.
    while not allotted_id:
        if not upper_exhausted:
            if dict2[upper_usr_id] == 0:
                print("ID {} inactive. Continuing search.".format(upper_usr_id))
                if upper_usr_id < max_id:
                    upper_usr_id += 1
                else:
                    upper_exhausted = True  # Maximum has been reached
            else:
                allotted_id = upper_usr_id
        if not lower_exhausted:
            if dict2[lower_usr_id] == 0:
                print("ID {} inactive. Continuing search.".format(lower_usr_id))
                if lower_usr_id > min_id:
                    lower_usr_id -= 1
                else:
                    lower_exhausted = True  # Minimum has been reached
            else:
                allotted_id = lower_usr_id

        # Exhausted all values - No Data value
        if upper_exhausted and lower_exhausted:
            allotted_id = -999

    if allotted_id == -999:
        print("Couldn't allot an ID")
    else:
        print("Allotted ID is: {}".format(allotted_id))

allot()
```

Comment: Just an FYI - The second code block will raise an exception if all `dict2` keys have value as `0`, as `while` loop will not break

Comment: Yup! Just noticed. The code searches all the keys now, which the original code does not.

Comment: @Nebulous29: your suggested code is suitable for me. But, my expectation is: '3' is my base key. if '3'==0 means I want select the next nearest active key as per its position (either left or right side). As per my case 3 dict2 arrangement  next nearest active key is '2' rather than '5'. Guide me the possibility to select '2' rather than '5' (without normal iteration).

Comment: @user12207831 Oh, sorry! Missed that in the initial description. That's a pretty easy fix. See the updated code for more details :)

Comment: @Nebulous29: My expected code is now I got it..Thank you very much..

Answer (score 0):

I suggest a different approach (Dont know how flexible you are with your approach)-

Store your data like this

```
dict2 = {"1": {1, 2, 5}, "0": {3, 4}} # 1 for available Ids and 0 for allocated
```

Now for any incoming user id

```
if usr_id in dict2["1"]:
    allotted_id = usr_id
elif usr_id in dict2["0"]:
    # either return the first available Or
    # traverse and return the next higher user id available 
else:
    # exception
```

Comment: Looking up items in lists (`if foo in mylist`) is not efficient. Internally each item in the list is checked in turn. You should use a set (or dict keys) to do this lookup efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

I would use numpy:

```
user_ids = np.array(range(5))
valid_user = np.array([1, 1, 0, 0, 1])
anchor_id = 2

dist_from_anchor = np.abs(user_ids - anchor_id)
dist_from_anchor[valid_user == 0] = len(user_ids) +1 #will not be the min
print(np.argmin(dist_from_anchor))
```

I used the minimum user_id as 0 (just a cs thing...) but you can easily change it to be 1...